# Android popup dialog screen size doesn't change in android Oreo

Tags: android, popup, width

I'm working on android project. I want to show a popup dialog inside my activity. I have implemented it (All the codes attached below). But my question is, when I run this project in android the popup shows like this. **I need to increase the width of this popup dialog. I tried a few solutions, but didn't work for me.** Please help me to solve this matter. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Here is my code**

**xml file--**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="MSGP3006"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="QTY:2 | Weight : 500g | Discount::25%"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Rs.360.00"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textColor="@color/Sky_Dark_Blue"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**java file--**

```
public class AddInvoiceDialog extends Dialog {

    public Activity activity;
    public Dialog dialog;
    public Button btn_add;

    public AddInvoiceDialog(Activity a) {
        super(a);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.activity = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.inv_add_new_invoice_popup);

        btn_add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                activity.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your layout file contain root horizontal linear layout..Try to correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below line after `setContentView(R.layout.inv_add_new_invoice_popup);`

```
getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

You will get popup window matching device width.

You also need to add `android:orientation="vertical"` in your parent `LinearLayout`, it contains multiple child.

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom view in Alert Dialog as mentioned below :

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inv_add_new_invoice_popup, null);
        alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();